# Update multiple objects in Django 1.5 with formsets

Tags: python, django, django-forms, primary-key, django-class-based-views

How can I update multiple objects in Django 1.5 with formsets? I guess the url should be something like `/4,7,8/update/` where 4, 7, and 8 are primary keys of the objects I want to update.

I guess there may be someone who already solved this problem, but I can't find any projects with this feature. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Use a form and a generic url and pass the id's via POST:

```
/myobject/update/
```

In your view you could process the formset like so:

```
formset = MyFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        # do something with the formset.cleaned_data
```

Take a closer read at the [django formset docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/).